# JavaFX - Editing TableView doesn't update model property

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a TableView using the the code below;

```
TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
firstNameCol .setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
tableView.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);
tableView.getItems().add(new Person("John"));
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn()));
```

and my Model is the following;

```
class Person{

   private SimpleStringProperty firstName;

   public Person(String firstName){
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
   }

   public final void setFirstName(String value){
         firstName.set(value);
         System.out.println("first name updated");
   }

   public final String getFirstName(){
        return firstName.get();
   }

   public SimpleStringProperty firstNameProperty(){
        return firstName;
   }
}
```

Now, when I edit the First Name column I should get the "first name updated" output but I am not, which means the set method of the model's property doesn't get called. Shouldn't this be the case or my understanding is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MS90 This is just the title of the Column. The binding happens in this line: `firstNameCol .setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());`

Comment: How about setting property there as new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName")?

Comment: Same result, set method doesn't get invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return the property from the `cellValueFactory`. Assuming you do not specify a `onEditCommit` event handler for the the column, the `SimpleStringProperty` object is modified. The setter method of the class containing the field is not involved.

You should be able to verify this by adding a listener to the property in the constructor or by extending `SimpleStringProperty`:

```
this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName) {

    @Override
    public void set(String value) {
        super.set(value);
        System.out.println("first name updated (SimpleStringProperty.set)");
    }

};
```

or

```
this.firstName.addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("first name updated (SimpleStringProperty.set)"));
```